# Integral of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{t}e^{-\frac{t^2}{4}}\int_0^{\frac{t}{2}}e^{u^2}dudt$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to calculate the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{t}e^{-\frac{t^2}{4}}\int_0^{\frac{t}{2}}e^{u^2}dudt\ \ ?$$
I don't understand how to calculate. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I have rewritten it.

Comment: The absolute value sign on $1/|t|$ changes the integral.

Answer (score 6):

With the substitution $u\to\frac{t}2x$, the inner integral becomes
$$\int_0^{\frac{t}{2}}e^{u^2}\,du=\frac{t}2\int^1_0e^{\frac{t^2}{4}x^2}\,dx,$$
implying
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{t}e^{-\frac{t^2}{4}}\int_0^{\frac{t}{2}}e^{u^2}\,du\,dt=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int^1_0 e^{-\frac{t^2}{4}(1-x^2)}\,dx\,dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int^1_0 e^{-s^2(1-x^2)}\,dx\,ds.$$
Since the integrand is positive, Mr. Fubini encourages us to change the order of integration, and
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-s^2(1-x^2)}\,ds=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$ Now clearly $$\int^1_0\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=\frac{\pi}2,$$
so we arrive at $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{t}e^{-\frac{t^2}{4}}\int_0^{\frac{t}{2}}e^{u^2}\,du\,dt=\frac{\pi^{3/2}}2.$$

Comment: That's Dr. Fubini.  He didn't go to Fubini graduate school for four years to be called Mister, thank you very much.   I hope you got the obscure reference.  Anyway, I posted a solution that uses Feynman's trick to supplement your solid way forward.  And Happy New Year!

Comment: how you justify the use of Fubini theorem for a improper integral of Riemann?

Comment: @Masacroso Erm... sorry? That's meant as a Lebesgue integral, naturally.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought it might be instructive to apply Feynman's trick of differentiating under the integral to evaluate the integral of interest.  To that end, we now proceed.

---

Let $I(a)$, $a> 1$, be the integral given by

$$\begin{align}
I(a)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-at^2/4}}{t}\int_0^{t/2}e^{u^2}\,du\,dt\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{t/2\,\mapsto \,t}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-at^2}}{t}\int_0^{t}e^{u^2}\,du\,dt\tag1
\end{align}$$

---

Differentiating $(1)$ reveals

$$I'(a)=- \int_{-\infty}^\infty te^{-at^2} \int_0^{t}e^{u^2}\,du\,dt\tag2 $$

---

Next, integrating by parts the (outer) integral in $(2)$ with $u=\int_0^{t}e^{u^2}\,du$ and $v=-\frac2a e^{-at^2}$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
I'(a)&=-\frac1{2a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(a-1)t^2}\,dt\\\\
&=-\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2a\sqrt{a-1}}\tag3
\end{align}$$

---

Integrating $(3)$ and using $\lim_{a\to \infty}I(a)=0$, we arrive at

$$\begin{align}
I(a)&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2 \int_a^\infty \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x-1}}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{2}-\sqrt{\pi}\arctan(\sqrt{a-1})\tag 4
\end{align}$$

---

Finally, taking the limit as $a\to 1^+$ yields the coveted integral

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-t^2/4}}{t}\int_0^{t/2}e^{u^2}\,du\,dt=\frac{\pi^{3/2}}{2}}$$

And we are done!

---

Comment: Thanks, nice answer (and nice comment, above, I'll apologize to Dr. Fubini next time we meet)! Happy New Year!

Comment: @ProfessorVector You're welcome, and thank you.  I'm not certain if you got the obscure reference, which was a paraphrase of a line in one of the Austin Powers' movies.

Comment: I'm certain I didn't get it, I've never considered watching that movie.

Comment: how you justify the use of Leibniz rule (aka "differentiating under the integral sign") of an improper integral?

Comment: @masacroso The integral of the differentiated integrand converges uniformly.

Comment: @MarkViola thank you for the clarification. I see that $|I'(a)|$ is bounded for $a\in[1+\epsilon,\infty)$ for some arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ but it doesnt if $a\in(1,\infty)$, so by the M-test we cant confirm uniform convergence in this last open interval, is that right? In this case, how you can justify take the limit $a\to 1^+$ in the last step?

Comment: You're correct.  It's UC for all $a\ge 1+\epsilon$, for all positive $\epsilon $.  And we can differentiate under the integral.  The result is applicable on the union of sets $a\ge 1+\epsilon$, which is the set $a>1$.  Hence, we can take the limit as $a\to 1^+$.